# Slick3.2 Error: No matching Shape found

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I'm not sure what is wrong here.

The following code block is throwing error:

```
   (for {
      (e,r) <- tblDetail.joinLeft(tblMaster).on((e,r) => r.col1 === e.col3)
    } yield (e.id)
```

**Error**

```
No matching Shape found.
[error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.
[error] Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection,
[error]  you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List),
[error]  or you forgot to import a driver api into scope.
[error]   Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
[error]      Source type: (slick.lifted.Rep[Int], slick.lifted.Rep[String],...)
[error]    Unpacked type: T
[error]      Packed type: G
[error]           (e,r) <- tblDetail.joinLeft(tblMaster).on((e,r) => r.col1 === e.col3)
```

I checked the Slick Tables for `tblDetail` and `tblMaster` they seemed to be fine.

**tblMaster**

```
class TblMaster(tag:Tag)
    extends Table[(Int,String,...)](tag, "tbl_master") {
  def id                  = column[Int]("id")
  def col3  = column[String]("col3")

  def * = (id,col3)
}
```

**tblDetail**

```
class TblDetail(tag:Tag)
    extends Table[Entity](tag, "tbl_detail") {
  def id                  = column[Int]("id")
  def col1  = column[String]("col1")

  def * : ProvenShape[Entity] = (id,col1) <>
           ((Entity.apply _).tupled, Entity.unapply)
}
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: My wild guess is there is something wrong with the TblMaster `*` method. There is `...` on the tuple for the Table, so I guess there are other type that you just hide. It looks like those types are missing from the tuple: `(id,col3)`.